# Python: why is random.randint(1,100) returning two values?

Tags: python

I'm trying to work through python assignments because I already know java and C#, and managed to place out of the python class in my college with my AP Computer Science score.

This is a SetTitle function that I have created. 
The Write function has already been implemented in the given class.

```
class HTMLOutputFile:

def SetTitle( title ):
    if not str(title):
        return false
    else:
        Write("<TITLE>",title,"<TITLE>")
        return true
```

This file is calling my SetTitle method to make sure it works properly.

```
from htmloutputfile import *
import random

MyHTMLOutputFile = HTMLOutputFile()

if MyHTMLOutputFile.SetTitle(random.randint(1,100)):
    print('Error: SetTitle accepted non-string')
    exit(0)

if not MyHTMLOutputFile.SetTitle('My Title'):
    print('Error: SetTitle did not accept string')
    exit(0)
```

But, when I run it, I receive the error

```
if MyHTMLOutputFile.SetTitle(random.randint(1,100)):
TypeError: SetTitle() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Do you guys have any ideas why random.randint(1,100) might be considered as two arguments instead of 1? I don't need a direct fix if you don't want to give it to me, but I'd like a point in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

change

```
def SetTitle( title ):
```

to

```
def SetTitle(self, title ):
```

Each class method must have the first parameter the instance the method is called on. It thinks it is two arguments because it automatically passes self to the function.

[What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python)

Comment: Thank you! So in that case if the Write method was defined as Write(self,outstring) would i have to pass that in within the SetTitle method?

Comment: No, that is done automatically. Which is why it said there was 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`randint` is generating only one value, but since this is a method of the class, you need to use `self` as the first argument -

```
class HTMLOutputFile:

    def SetTitle(self, title):
        if not str(title):
            return false
        else:
            Write("<TITLE>",title,"<TITLE>")
            return true
```

Also note a couple of things - the method needs to be indented within the class. And python uses `True` and `False` (note the capitalization)